# Java 8: Map of field to list of items

Tags: java, filter, java-8, mapping, java-stream

Lets say I have a `List<Person> Gathering` and I want a `Map<String, List<Person>>`, mapping `Person.surname` to a `List` of `Person`:s that have the same `surname`. Is there a convenient way to do this using streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using [`Collectors.groupingBy(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<String, List<Person>> personsBySurname = gathering.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::get‌​Surname));
```